# Error with launch_url plugin in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to use launch_url plugin in Flutter but my app keeps quitting immediately as I click the button.

Code I use for the button:

```
new MaterialButton(
      child: const Text('M-COM'),
      height: 50.0,
      minWidth: 200.0,
      color: Colors.blue,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      onPressed: _launchURL,
)
```

Code for _launchURL:

```
_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://flutter.io';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Imports:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'dart:async';
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  url_launcher:
```

Error I get:

```
F/libc    ( 6730): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xd in tid 6748 (Thread-2), pid 6730 (.flutterstarter)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:9/PPP4.180612.007/4860066:userdebug/dev-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 6730, tid: 6748, name: Thread-2  >>> com.yourcompany.flutterstarter <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xd
Cause: null pointer dereference
    eax c8e6faac  ebx c8e6faac  ecx 0000000a  edx c7e0f570
    edi c5d175f0  esi c7e10408
    ebp c7e0f468  esp c7e0f468  eip c84aa1d8
backtrace:
    #00 pc 006981d8  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #01 pc 008f5b75  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #02 pc 008e87ea  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #03 pc 008ffb03  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #04 pc 008eb310  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #05 pc 008f5eea  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #06 pc 008e87ea  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #07 pc 008fe2fb  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #08 pc 008e8d97  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #09 pc 008fdcb7  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #10 pc 008eafb7  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #11 pc 008f997f  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #12 pc 008eaff8  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #13 pc 008fa175  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #14 pc 008eaf8a  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #15 pc 008f997f  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #16 pc 008eaff8  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #17 pc 008fcc16  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #18 pc 008eb034  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #19 pc 008ef41e  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #20 pc 008f0570  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #21 pc 0091433e  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #22 pc 0092fad4  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #23 pc 00932f2a  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #24 pc 00934573  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #25 pc 00933d2b  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #26 pc 0093004a  /data/app/com.yourcompany.flutterstarter-MdONNcPhZQnLdPJuB2HJaQ==/lib/x86/libflutter.so
    #27 pc 0000056b  <anonymous:c6440000>
Lost connection to device.
```

I am using Android Studio and trying to run the app on Android. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What Flutter version are you using? I got a similar error (for different code) but the latest `dev` channel build fixed it for me.

Comment: I am using v0.5.1-beta. Which dev version are you using?

Comment: Currently I am using the `master` channel. `flutter channel master` because it fixes a blocking bug for me, besides that using `master` is rather discouraged. Normally `beta` and `dev` should be preferred.